# Work with Vuejs and normal Javascript (vanilla)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, vue.js

I need to use Vue and call another function in normal javascript, also need to change some variables in Vue and read them in Javascript after.

The solution on internet is to insert normal javascript functions into a Vue component (meaning move everything to Vue), but some functions are too big or too complicated to refacture to Vue.

So, i need a way to work with variables and functions between Vanilla Javascript and Vue, in the meantime i move everything to Vue.

Comment: `move everything to Vue` ... no ... Vue is not a different language ... it's just "normal" javascript ... you can use existing functions without "moving them to vue" - by the way if you're using jquery with vue, you're probably programming wrong

Comment: Im moving everything to Vue, but cant do everything at the same time, migrating everything to Vue will take some months, and the site needs to keep going, until i move everything to Vue, i need to use both

Answer (score 0):

After a while i found a Solution (Workaround):

The only way possible i know to comunicate between normal javascript, PHP, Laravel and Vuejs, is using html tags as intermediaries, from them you can do all sort of stuff.

You can set any value from vue to a hidden input or a any DOM data, and read after from javascript, you can also trigger DOM events from Vue, and execute them in your regular Javascript.

This is a Workaround, since this is not optimal use of Vuejs, but if you need to use Vue and still use normal javascript, hope this will help you.

For example, to trigger a variable change in vue to Javascript:

In your Vue component:

```
<template>

    <input type="text" v-model="my_value" onchange="vanillaFunction(this.value)">

</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'test-vue',
    data: function (){
        return {
            my_value: 'start',
        }

    },
    created: function () {
        this.my_value = 'finish'
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.my_value = 'mounted'
    },
    watch: {
        my_value: function (val) {
            $("input#my_value").trigger('change')
        },
    },
};

</script>
```

In your javascript file:

```
function vanillaFunction(value){
    console.log('Vue has changed the value to: ' + value)
}
```

Comment: or `@change="vue_method_that_calls_vanilla"` and have a `method: vue_method_that_calls_vanilla() {}` that calls `vanillaFunction` - that way you can use components that don't have `onchange` HTML event handlers

Comment: but vanillaFunction needs to be a method inside the component, if is an outside function wont work

Comment: depends on how you import/load these "vanilla" functions - if they are loaded using the regular `<script>` tag, then any "global scoped" functions declared in those files are available to vue code (not `@change="xxx"` but for example a vue `method: a() { xxx() }` )